# I have two tables inside a parent table how can I make them both to have the same width?

Tags: html, css

This is my current situation: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsebasct/5e76yoqd/) that looks like the image below

```
--------------------------------------------------
// table0
     ---------------------------
     |                         |
                word           |
     |                         |
     |                         |
     ---------------------------
// table1
 ------------------------------------
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 ------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want to have something like this

```
outer table
------------------------------------------------------
// table0
 ------------------------------------
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 ------------------------------------
// table1
 ------------------------------------
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 ------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
```

I mean to have both tables have the same width

Edit: A Fixed with is not a desired solution, since users could seen this from its phone too. I need to have to be kind of flexible whether seen from mobile or desktop

Edit: I copy the code here due to some comments

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .containerTitleTable {
            padding: 0px;
            cellpadding: 0px;
            background-color: gray;
        }


        .containerBodyTable {
            border-radius: 30px;
            background-color: #F8F7FC;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="backgroundTable" align="center" >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="titleTable" align="center" class="containerTitleTable" cellpadding="0">
                    
                    <tr align="center"> 
                        <td bgcolor="#F2EDF9" >
                            <p>
                                <h4>
                                    <span >!Bienvenid@, [[${nombre}]]</span>
                                </h4>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>


            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="bodyTable" class="containerBodyTable" >


                    <tr align="center">
                        <td >
                            <p>
                                <h1>
                                    <span >!Bienvenid@, [[${nombre}]]</span>
                                </h1>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: @AnkitKumar the Fiddle can't be seen ?

Comment: `#backgroundTable table { width:100%; }`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: More importantly, this is not tabular data so you should NOT be using tables in the first place.

Comment: @Paulie_D valuable observation, what should I use instead ?

Answer (score -1):

yes it can please put your both td size width. this should work

```
<td style ="width:397px">
```

Answer (score -1):

Its very easy. Just add `width` parameter in your table like `<table width=90%></table>`